# Apps Script, Need function to only work on certain cells but can't get code to work

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Need help please. Below code works (very slowly) but needs extra function to speed things up.

**Purpose of current code:** looks at multiple sheets to perform a "find and replace" against a dictionary (the dictionary is pretty big but reduced it for here).

**The issue:** It runs really slow because it looks through every single cell.

**Solution needed please:** Need to tell code to only look at L2:P100 on all the sheets (there are about 15 but 2 here for demonstration).

I've spent all day trying to make it work and trying lots of code from here but keep getting dataRange related issues.
Any ideas what can be done to have it only look at certain cells i.e. a range of cells? I thought it would be as straightforward as dataRange(L2:P100); but get null errors, undefined etc.
I know it's a bit messy and probably has some unneeded variables... have been trying out so many things it's kind of gotten a bit messy as a result. Don't feel bad for pointing these out. I'm sort of new to coding, have some practice but not a lot, so I'm not fully understanding of things just yet. But trying to learn.
Thank you!

```
function FindReplace() {

var r,sheet,sheets,ss;
var data_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
var num_rows = data_range.getNumRows();
var num_columns = data_range.getNumColumns();
var sheets = ["firstsheet","secondsheet"];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = 0;
var startRow = 1;
var startColumn= 1;
var lastRow = 100;
var lastColumn = 15;
var numRows = lastRow-startRow+1;
var numCols = lastColumn-startColumn+1;
var find_replace = {
     /* Dictionary */
    "AA": "Done",
    "BB": "Check",
    "CC": "Complete",
  }

for (r=0;r<5;r++){
  sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sheets[r]);
  Object.keys(find_replace).map(function(find) {
var replace = find_replace[find];
for (var row=1; row <= num_rows; row++) {
 for (var col=1; col <= num_columns; col++) {
    var value = data_range.getCell(row, col).getValue();
    if (data_range.getCell(row, col).getFormula()) {continue;}
    try {
       value = value.replace(find, replace);
       data_range.getCell(row, col).setValue(value);
    }
    catch (err) {continue;}
          }
        }
  });


}
```

}

Comment: What if `AA ` is produced by a formula? You loop over all the rows and columns one by one.. You want to get all the data at once and loop over it when it is stored in memory as an array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.
- You want to replace the values in the range of "L2:P100".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, it seems that `var sheets = ["firstsheet", "secondsheet"];` is not used. Because `sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[r]);` in the loop is not used. In your script, only the active sheet is used.
- When `getValue`, `setValue`, `getFormula` are used in a loop, the process cost will be high.

  - I think that the reason for `Below code works (very slowly)` is due to this.
- In your script, it seems that all cells in a sheet are used. In order to use the limited range, it is required to be modified.

When these points are reflected in a Google Apps Script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save the script. And, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please run `FindReplace2`. By this, the script is run.

```js
function FindReplace2() {
  const sheetNames = ["firstsheet", "secondsheet"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use.
  const range = "L2:P100"; // Please set the range you want to use.
  const find_replace = { // This is from your script.
    "AA": "Done",
    "BB": "Check",
    "CC": "Complete",
  };

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const tempRange = ss.getRange(range);
  const startRowIndex = tempRange.getRow() - 1;
  const endRowIndex = startRowIndex + tempRange.getNumRows();
  const startColumnIndex = tempRange.getColumn() - 1;
  const endColumnIndex = startColumnIndex + tempRange.getNumColumns();
  const ar = Object.entries(find_replace);
  const requests = sheetNames.flatMap(n => {
    const sheetId = ss.getSheetByName(n).getSheetId();
    return ar.map(([find, replacement]) => (
      {
        findReplace: {
          find,
          replacement,
          range: { sheetId, startRowIndex, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex },
          matchEntireCell: true,
        },
      })
    );
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, the cell values of `range` of `sheetNames` are replaced using `find_replace`.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: High-Efficiency Finding and Replacing Many Values in Google Spreadsheet with Low Process Cost using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/6fc2f3ea6d09ce2906e7922c76c0b238)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: This worked! Thank you - I got pulled into other projects and was finally able to revisit and test. This works and it works way quicker than any previous attempt I made... on about 15 sheets with about 10 find and replace cases, it takes 2-3 secs to update the entire thing! Perfect - again thank you.

Comment: It also does work vs my attempt which didn't. I'm studying your changes to understand what needed doing, but it's above my skill level, so no chance I could have solved this myself. Thanks so much for understanding the issue so well from 1 request and for being able to work out a solid solution. Much appreciated! I have a lot of learning to do...

Comment: @heythere Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe what you were trying to accomplish

```
function FindReplace() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = ["firstsheet", "secondsheet"];
  var rObj = {pA:["AA","BB","CC"], "AA": "Done", "BB": "Check", "CC": "Complete" };
  sht.forEach(sh => {
    rObj.pA.forEach(p => {
      sh.getDataRange().createTextFinder(p).replaceAllWith(rObj[p])
    });
  });
}
```

References:

[TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)